# Disable cache in shared hosting Fat Free framework

Tags: debugging, caching, shared-hosting, fat-free-framework

I cannot get to disable cache in shared hosting. When I set

```html
$f3->set('DEBUG', 3);
$f3->set('LOCALES', 'lang/');
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD', 'app/controllers/');
$f3->set('UI', 'app/views/');
$f3->set('CACHE', FALSE);
$f3->clear('CACHE');
$cache->reset();
```

Cache still working and I cannot properly debug

Comment: `$f3->set('CACHE',FALSE)` is enough to disable it. What makes you think that cache is still enabled?

Comment: files in /tmp folder automatically generated every time I refresh browser.
Also, cannot see any changed on developing. Every time I must wait for couple minutes to see new changes

Comment: `tmp/` or `tmp/cache/`? The `Template` class generates compiled PHP files inside the `tmp/` folder, whatever the value of `CACHE` is. Those compiled files are automatically regenerated whenever the original template files are modified.

Comment: inside tmp/,  how to disable template generation ?

Comment: also how you develop if not see any changes on browser ? Only after couple of minutes

Comment: You can't disable template generation. Usually you don't need to cleanup those files because they are automatically regenerated whenever the original file is modified. The only case where a manual cleanup is required is when [custom tags](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/extended-templating) are modified. Are you using custom tags?

Comment: No Im using F3 template engine 

So what should I do to develop faster and do not wait when changes occur on browser ?
P. S. Developing from shared hosting

Comment: The delay you're talking about could come from your shared hosting. Maybe they're using a [web accelerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accelerator)? I advise you to develop on a local server and upload to shared hosting once it's ready.

Comment: thank you, will try and inform

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it was due to `Zend OPcache` module. All I need is to insert 
`php_flag opcache.enable Off` into `.htaccess` file